Amusing historical nicknames for the patent office?
I'm looking for amusing (including disparaging) nicknames for the USPTO that can be traced back to an historical primary source, including but not limited to famous inventors such as Thomas Edison or his ilk. Google and ChatGPT have been unable to do so, although ChatGPT of course thinks it has! Thanks!

This probably looks familiar ;-) ... https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/25826/nicknames-for-the-uspto

I've also posted the question there. Thanks!

"Perpetual Tort Opportunities".  I just made that up on the spot, though.

@StephenGucker Generally it's best to avoid posting a question on multiple sites at once; that creates a situation where people on one site spend time unnecessarily answering a question that's already been answered on the other.

If this is something Edison used among his colleagues, rather than something that has become common in the language, I wouldn't expect the ELU members to know it. Usually SE sites specific to an industry or field are best for questions about jargon.

Do you have any reason to believe that sobriquets, epithets or witty names were ever used?

This doesn't seem on-topic, but your best bet is probably to find old histories of the USPTO or articles about historical attitudes to the patent office. They're likely to mention any amusing invective directed at the USPTO.

@alphabet The question was closed on the patents stack exchange as being off-topic & I didn't get any responses.

@Mari-Lou A I was told years ago by a supervisor at the USPTO that the hard-copy OED (which he kept on a pedestal l in his office) listed "Nut House" as a synonym for the patent office, but when I checked the online OED recently, it wasn't listed.
